# XML editor like Word 2003

Tags: xml, editor, word-2003

I search an XML Editor focus on text annotation like Word 2003 ([Screenshot](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://i.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/gallery/322865-500-277.jpg)), where xml tag are inline, and where you could select text and suround it with tag in one click.

Answer (score 4):

`<oXygen/>` is the best XML editor available, with a large number of users ranging from beginners to XML experts. 
       
   It is the only XML tool that supports all the XML schema languages. The XSLT and XQuery support is enhanced with powerful debuggers and performance profilers.
       You can use `<oXygen/>` XML Editor to work with all XML-based technologies including XML databases, XProc pipelines, and web services.

### **Features**

- XML IDE
- Intelligent XML editing
- XML Validation
- XML Schema Modeling
- XPath Support

And many more other features.

You can get more detail [XML Editor](http://www.oxygenxml.com/)

Comment: XML Editor = XML Developer + XML Author in its website obviously says this and another person ( @David W ) already written about XML Author so dont get me wrong but your answer is a posible duplicate!

Answer (score 2):

I like the oXygen products.  [XML Author](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_author.html) is the low end product that does what I think you want.  There is a download and trial.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [XML Notepad 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7973)

Comment: In fact XML Notepad 2007 is what I do not want. The text flow is transformed as a tree, and I want the original flow.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try [Altova XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/xml-editor/).

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is [XML Copy Editor](http://xml-copy-editor.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) with the [XML plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/XML%20Tools/), which can easily be installed via the plugin manager. Gives your choice of flow or tree view and you can collapse, as well as other bonus features like *Validate against XSD schemas* and *Transform via XSLT*.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you got the cash for it, I'd prefer [EditX](http://www.editix.com/) or if you want a free solution [EditX Lite](http://free.editix.com/download.html) is what you need..

Features of EditiX Lite :

[XML Editor](http://free.editix.com/features/xml_editor.html)

[XSLT Editor](http://free.editix.com/features/xslt_editor.html) and [Debugger](http://free.editix.com/features/xslt_debugger.html) (1.0 and 2.0)

[Open XML Format Editor](http://free.editix.com/features/open_xml_editor.html)

[Open Document Format](http://free.editix.com/features/open_document_editor.html)

[Visual Schema Editor](http://free.editix.com/features/schema_editor.html)

[XML Differencing](http://free.editix.com/features.html#XML_Diff)

Edit:

This also includes the feature [Powerful XPath builder/research](http://free.editix.com/)

I really like this tool hope helps you too.